# Exporting multiple panels of plots and data to *.png (in the style layout() works within R)

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to export multiple panels of data and 1 plot as a single image using either the .png device or .pdf device and I'm not meeting with any success.  I can produce the image that I want within R using the R native plotting device, but when I try to produce the same image directly, I get results that I do not anticipate.

Here is my example code

```
testMat <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 5)##  create data
testMatDF <- as.data.frame(testMat)
names(testMatDF) <- c("Hey there", "Column 2", 
         "Some * Symbols", "And ^ More", 
         "Final Column")
rownames(testMatDF) <- paste("Group", 1:4)

library(gplots) ##  gplots needed for textplot()
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),  2, 3, byrow = TRUE))
curve(dnorm, -3, 4)
textplot(testMat)
textplot(testMatDF)
##  produces what I want within R

layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),  2, 3, byrow = TRUE))
png(file='plot1.png')
curve(dnorm, -3, 4)
textplot(testMat)
textplot(testMatDF)
dev.off()
##  only the last function texplot(testMatDF) gets output, not what I anticipated
```

I've also tried the `mfrow()` graphical parameter without success.

```
par(mfrow= c(3, 1))
png(file='plot2.png')
curve(dnorm, -3, 4)
textplot(testMat)
textplot(testMatDF)
dev.off()
##  only the last function texplot(testMatDF) gets output
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you move your calls to `par` or `layout` after you open your graphics device, it should work correctly.

```
png(file='plot2.png')
par(mfrow= c(3, 1))
curve(dnorm, -3, 4)
textplot(testMat)
textplot(testMatDF)
dev.off()
```

Comment: @Chris glad to hear it. FWIW, before you start plotting, your device needs to be open including the layout of your canvas.  Also, as you use other plotting tools, you may find you need `print()` around your plots, particularly with `ggplot2` (not to be confused with `gplots`).

Comment: Yes.  Amen to that!  That was a lesson learned the hard way.  Cheers!