# How to combine 4 graphs into one image

Tags: r

I have four mini graphs that I would like to combine into one image. Is this possible to achieve in base R?

```
 #graphs1
 par(mar=c(0, 5, 0, 2.1))
 H <- c(0, 0, 2, 0, 21) # Create the data for the chart, cont3.#
 M <- c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High")

  barplot(H, col =c("slategray1", "slategray1","slategray1",
                             "slategray1", "steelblue3"), 
  horiz = TRUE, 
  family="Arial", border = NA, names.arg = M, 
  xlim = range(0,100), ylim = range(0, 0.08), 
  axes = FALSE, width = 0.01, las=1, xaxt='n') 

  #graph2
  par(mar=c(0, 5, 0, 2.1))

  H <- c(0, 0, 1, 4, 18) # Create the data for the chart
  M <- c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High")

  barplot(H, col =c("slategray1", "slategray1","slategray1",
              "slategray1", "steelblue3"), 
    horiz = TRUE, 
    family="Arial", border = NA, names.arg = M, 
    xlim = range(0,100), ylim = range(0, 0.08), 
    axes = FALSE, width = 0.01, las=1, xaxt='n') 

  #graphs3
  par(mar=c(0, 5, 0, 2.1))

  H <- c(0, 1, 3, 4, 14) # Create the data for the chart 
  M <- c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High")

  barplot(H, col =c("slategray1", "slategray1","slategray1",
              "slategray1", "steelblue3"), 
    horiz = TRUE, 
    family="Arial", border = NA, names.arg = M, 
    xlim = range(0,100), ylim = range(0, 0.08), 
    axes = FALSE, width = 0.01, las=1, xaxt='n') 

 #graph4
 par(mar=c(0, 5, 0, 2.1))
 H <- c(0, 1, 4, 4, 16) # Create the data for the chart, cont3.#
 M <- c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High")

 barplot(H, col =c("slategray1", "slategray1","slategray1",
              "slategray1", "steelblue3"), 
    horiz = TRUE, 
    family="Arial", border = NA, names.arg = M, 
    xlim = range(0,100), ylim = range(0, 0.08), 
    axes = FALSE, width = 0.01, las=1, xaxt='n')
```

I would like the four graphs created in the code above to be combined into one image in base R.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting multiple panels of plots and data to \*.png (in the style layout() works within R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829365/exporting-multiple-panels-of-plots-and-data-to-png-in-the-style-layout-work)

Answer (score 2):

Before you create the first plot, run:

`par(mfrow = c(2,2))`

to place the four plots on a 2 x 2 grid, that can be exported as one image.

Comment: It's also good to run `par(mfrow = c(1,1))` afterwards to return to the normal plotting behaviour.

Comment: True, and I also like to run `par(mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))` not too infrequently!